# AWS CloudTrail: deliver filtered logs to CloudWatch Logs without writing to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

AWS **CloudTrail** provides with management API calls bulk logging, but logs are monstrous, only viewable & downloadable. There is also the option to set multi- or single-regional single- or cross-account **"Trails"**, which can log only a) system management API calls, only "read", only "write" (create/change) or both; b) object-level selected **S3** buckets (storage) API calls & c) selected **Lambda**(serverless) functions API calls. While **CloudWatch Logs** expose system components faults, state change events etc. So the former is about security and the latter is about system health, also providing with metrics, graphs, dashboards etc, including custom. It also allows quite comfortable logs processing and analysis. The **Trails** logs can be copied to **CloudWatch** and fetched with API (it was my plan), but namely copied, because **Trails** always store logs in a **S3** bucket... in ~5-minutes chunks gziped into files with counter-intuitive names under hilarious directory (prefix) structure, and nobody (hey, AWS, maybe you? :D) can change it. To add, such logging storage method costs double-triple vs small web-site hosted on similar **S3** bucket due to much i/o and encryption. But most important, these logs are very hard to process for my purpose: to catch resource-creating API calls, so if I don't find lower-level approach, I have to importing to **CloudWatch**, filter there (at additional cost) and export to my tags processor. Too much for tagging automation to be a part of low cost and low price app... So:

1. How to skip **S3**? Could deny-access bucket policy help?
2. Is it possible to filter unnecessary events prior to feeding **CloudWatch Log**?

To be precise: i'd like to log only creation of taggable resources to implement sophisticated auto-tagging. Maybe it can be resolved without **CloudWatch**, too?

Thank you in advance, I am not really deep in AWS logging and short of time

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is a little confusing. Could you possibly edit your question to provide more detail? For example, can you explain the flow of the log data? When you say "skip S3", what is the normal path of the log data? Please explain in enough detail so that most readers can understand your setup and what you would like to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , thank you for your comment, hope all is clear now. The fact is, I can be advised only by someone with deep AWS knowledge, that's why  first version was short and lacked what you asked. But you're right, indeed, StackOverflow posts must be iinformative. [Short comparison](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-CloudTrail-and-CloudWatch), [AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-management-and-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html). GL!